# How to numerically sort IP address

Tags: python

I have a list of dict having ip address. i want to sort them numerically

```
a = [{'from': '10.246.47.121' },{'from': '10.60.0.111'}, {'from': '192.168.156.113'}, {'from': '192.168.20.100'}]
```

below is my code

```
b = sorted(a, key=operator.itemgetter('from'))
```

this is giving the following output

```
[{'from': '10.246.47.121'}, {'from': '10.60.0.111'}, {'from': '192.168.156.113'}, {'from': '192.168.20.100'}]
```

i want to get output like this

```
a = [{'from': '10.60.0.111'}, {'from': '10.246.47.121' }, {'from': '192.168.20.100'}, {'from': '192.168.156.113'}]
```

any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this

```
a.sort(key=lambda x: [int(y) for y in x['from'].split('.')])
```